# What is a permissioned blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, permissioned-chain

What is the meaning of a permissioned blockchain? I know it is a private blockchain, but why is it called permissioned?

Answer (score 2):

In a permissioned blockchain, there are restrictions on who can participate (ie. users need 'permission to join the network). It is generally opposed to a 'public' blockchain where anyone can participate.

This eliminates the need for 'Byzantine fault tolerance' as each of the possible 'miners' are known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you can compare it to a system with users having permission levels.

If it just a private blockchain, if someone knows the details about the network (bootnode, genisis file etc) he can join the network and run a full node with all permissions (participate in the consensus , auditing etc.)

But when it's a permissioned blockchain, some actions are limited to certain participants .

You may refer this [blog post](https://blog.darwinlabs.io/types-of-blockchain-public-private-and-permissioned-5b14fbfe38d4).